# Sort pandas grouped items with the highest count overall

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Say I have following dataframe:

```
d = {'col1': ["8","8","8","8","8","2","2","2","2","3","3"], 'col2': ['a', 'b','b','b','b','a','b','a','a','a','b'],
     'col3': ['m', 'n','z','b','a','ac','b1','ad','a1','a','b1'],'col4': ['m', 'n','z','b1','a','ac1','b31','a1d','3a1','a3','b1']}
test = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

In order to sort each grouped item with `count`, I could do the following:

```
test.groupby(["col1",'col2'])['col4'].count().reset_index(name="count").sort_values(["col1","count"],ascending=[True,False]).
```

It returns this table:

[image]

However, I want the group with `8` in `col1` to be the first item because this particular group has the highest count (i.e., 4).

How do I achieve this?

Edit: This is the expected output:

```
col1    col2    count
8       b        4
8       a        1
2       a        3
2       b        1
3       a        1
3       b        1
```

Comment: Can you provide the explicit expected output?

Comment: That's expected since you sort first by `col1` and then by `count`, i.e., `sort_values(["col1","count"],ascending=[True,False])`. If all you want to consider for the sort, then try `sort_values(by=["count"], ascending=False)`. This will break up the group members, however. You don't provide enough information as to how you want it to be sorted.

Comment: @harryhaller that will sort all the items by count not preserving the grouped item!

Comment: @mozway I have added the expected output

Comment: OK, then see my answer below (although it's still unclear to me if you want to use the max or total count of a group to sort the groups)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expected output is unclear, but assuming you want to sort the rows within each group by decreasing orders of count, and also the **groups with each other by decreasing order of the max (or total) count**.

```
(test.groupby(["col1",'col2'])['col4'].count()
     .reset_index(name="count")
     # using the max count per group, for the total use transform('sum')
     .assign(maxcount=lambda d: d.groupby('col1')['count'].transform('max'))
     .sort_values(['maxcount', 'count'], ascending=False)
     .drop(columns='maxcount')
)
```

Output:

```
  col1 col2  count
5    8    b      4
4    8    a      1
0    2    a      3
1    2    b      1
2    3    a      1
3    3    b      1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix your sorting in that case.
Your description is a bit unclear, therefore a general guideline to solving your problem.

Sort_values sorts from left to right, where the first item defines the order of the group and following items define the order, if the first item is equal.

Therefore, select the order of your columns in which you would like to sort and set the ascending parameter correctly.

Comment: For each group I want to sort descending by count. I also want to sort the group themselves again with count in descending order.